# disable previous date in pickmeup jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, pickmeup

I am a beginner. I want to disable all the previous dates so that user won't be able to select it.I tried everything but I am not able to disable it.Here is my Code: Please provide a demo if possible.

```
      var now = new Date;
        pickmeup(element, {
            render: function (date) {
                if (date < now) {
                    return { disabled: true, class_name: 'date-in-past' };
                }
                return {};
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've taken [the example from the GitHub](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#configuration-options) repo correct?

You need to specify the element you want to target.

```
var now = new Date;
pickmeup(element, {
    render : function (date) {
        if (date < now) {
            return {disabled : true, class_name : 'date-in-past'};
        }
        return {};
    } 
});
```

Change the element after `pickmeup` to the element you'd like. So if you wanted to target an element with the class `.mydatepicker`, change it to...

```
var now = new Date;
pickmeup('.mydatepicker', {
    render : function (date) {
        if (date < now) {
            return {disabled : true, class_name : 'date-in-past'};
        }
        return {};
    } 
});
```

Comment: I did and it worked but the problem is that two calendars overlapping. This is my Html and jquery code:

Comment: <div class="Reservation">
  <h4 style=" float:left; font-size:17px;">Check In:&nbsp;</h4><input  type="text" class="one" id="checkin" style="width: 120px; background-color:#480000; color:white; height: 22px" value="" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" class="two" id="checkout" style="width: 120px; background-color:#480000; left:5px; color:white; height: 22px" value="" />  <h4 style="left:420px; bottom:6px; position:absolute ">Guests:</h4> </div>

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {var input = $('.one'); var input2 =$('.two');pickmeup('.one', {position: 'bottom' ,hide_on_select:true,before_show: function () {  input.pickmeup('set_date', input.val(),true);}, change:function(formated) {input.val(formated);} });pickmeup('.two', {position: 'bottom',hide_on_select: true , before_show: function () {  input.pickmeup('set_date',input.val(),true);},change:function (formated) { input.val(formated);}
});var now = new Date;pickmeup('.Reservation',{ render: function (date) {if(date < now) {return{disabled: true, class_name: 'disabled' };}return {};}})